# Why does getline() cut off CSV Input?

Tags: c++, csv, parsing

I'm trying to read and parse my CSV files in C++ and ran into an error.

The CSV has 1-1000 rows and always 8 columns.

Generally what i would like to do is read the csv and output only lines that match a filter criteria. For example column 2 is timestamp and only in a specific time range.

My problem is that my program cuts off some lines.

At the point where the data is in the string record variable its not cutoff. As soon as I push it into the map of int/vector its cutoff. Am I doing something wrong here?

Could someone help me identify what the problem truly is or maybe even give me a better way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "csv.h"

using std::cout; using std::cerr;
using std::endl; using std::string;
using std::ifstream; using std::ostringstream;
using std::istringstream;

string readFileIntoString(const string& path) {
    auto ss = ostringstream{};
    ifstream input_file(path);
    if (!input_file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '"
            << path << "'" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ss << input_file.rdbuf();
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{

    int filterID = 3;
    int filterIDIndex = filterID;
    string filter = "System";

    /*Filter ID's:
        0 Record ID
        1 TimeStamp
        2 UTC
        3 UserID
        4 ObjectID
        5 Description
        6 Comment
        7 Checksum
    */
 
    string filename("C:/Storage Card SD/Audit.csv");
    string file_contents;
    std::map<int, std::vector<string>> csv_contents;
    char delimiter = ',';

    file_contents = readFileIntoString(filename);

    istringstream sstream(file_contents);
    std::vector<string> items;
    string record;

    int counter = 0;
    while (std::getline(sstream, record)) {
        istringstream line(record);
        while (std::getline(line, record, delimiter)) {
            items.push_back(record);
            cout << record << endl;
        }
        
        csv_contents[counter] = items;
        //cout << csv_contents[counter][0] << endl;
        items.clear();
        counter += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a line that isn't cut off and one that is?

Comment: This is the content of csv_contents ```0;"03.01.2022 09:28:30";"-1:00";"System";"Anwendung";"Runtime-Start von WinCC Runtime Advanced V17.0 am Bediengerõt lschiermann. Projekt: 'AuditTrail-Filter_V17.HMI - 0' Build 1
1;"03.01.2022 09:28:30";"-1:00";"System";"Anwendung";"Wechsel in die Betriebsart 'Online'.";;suavyY
2;"03.01.2022 09:28:31";"-1:00";"System";"Benutzerverwaltung";"Benutzerverwaltung importieren erfolgreich beendet.";;cDRs+P```      Line that starts with 0 is cut off the one that starts with 1 isnt

Comment: StackOverflow comes with a great feature. You can EDIT your question. To get this feature just klick on `edit`.  It's not necessary to extend your question in comments. The only reason to write a comment at the own question can be an answer to any other comment.

Comment: Appreciate the tip! :)

Comment: The code says the delimiter is , but the data says the delimiter is a ;.  Is that just a typo?

Comment: I see only 6 CSV fields in your raw data instead of 8 for record 0. Moreover, I see that most fields are surrounded with double-quotes.  When getline() looks for the delimiter, it doens't care for quotes.  So if you have a ; in the middle of a text field, it will consider it's a delimiter.  ALso,  are you sure that the original file doesn't use a line separator within a quote, as the [RFC 4180, section 2, item 6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) allows ?  This would result in recors pbroken in 2 in your reading logic.

Comment: @CodeGorilla Yes that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @Cristophe There are 8 fields. The 8 fields are the ones in the comment of the code where it says filter ID's. the comment field is empty most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see a reason why you data is being cropped, but I have refactored you code slightly and using this it might be easier for you to debug the problem, if it doesn't just disappear on its own.

```
int main()
{
    string path("D:/Audit.csv");

    ifstream input_file(path);
    if (!input_file.is_open()) 
    {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '" << path << "'" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::map<int, std::vector<string>> csv_contents;
    std::vector<string> items;
    string record;
    char delimiter = ';';

    int counter = 0;
    while (std::getline(input_file, record))
    {
        istringstream line(record);
        while (std::getline(line, record, delimiter))
        {
            items.push_back(record);
            cout << record << endl;
        }

        csv_contents[counter] = items;
        items.clear();
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I have tried your code and (after fixing the delimiter) had no problems, but I only had three lines of data, so if it is a memory issue it would have been unlikely to show.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning my code up a bit. Your code works like a charm, there is no more cropped text. Im not sure what the error with my version particularly is. But i continued with your version and am now implementing a filter for my Rows. Thanks Sir.